# Why kafka 0.10 console producer cannot send messages to kafka 0.9?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, versions, consumer, producer

Why kafka 0.10 console producer cannot send messages to kafka 0.9?

I am starting kafka console consumer in version 0.9 (on the server side).
I am starting kafka console producer in version 0.10 (on the client side).
Then I got in producer exception (below).

How it could be that new producer cannot send messages to old consumer?
Is it possible to set new producer in a kind of deprecated mode to send messages to old kafka?

$ bin\windows\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list my_server:9092 --topic my_topic

[2016-08-30 14:03:53,365] ERROR Uncaught error in kafka producer I/O thread:  (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'brokers': Error reading field 'host': Error reading string of length 25452, only 69 bytes available
        at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.Schema.read(Schema.java:73)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.parseResponse(NetworkClient.java:380)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleCompletedReceives(NetworkClient.java:449)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:269)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:229)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:134)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: The rule is `Upgrade brokers first, then clients. Not vice versa`

Comment: Thanks, but I get no point, why new kafka 0.10.0.0 Producer cannot speak to old Kafka Consumer 0.9.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka 0.10.0 introduced a new message format. I'm not completely sure but it looks like you're sending a message with the new format to a broker that clearly knows nothing about that.

You should try to force the 0.10 producer to use the old message format. Here you can find more info: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#upgrade_10_breaking

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the things are not so simple.

I had added interbroker.protocol.version=0.9.0.0, as my "opposite" Kafka is 0.9.0.0.Then I got exception:

[2016-08-31 08:08:27,809] FATAL  (kafka.Kafka$)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: log.message.format.version 0.10.0-IV1 cannot be used when inter.broker.protocol.version is set to 0.9.0.0

On the other hand in the JAVA Producer API I do not see any method that directly controls protocol, so I can from JAVA API 0.10.0.0 send messages to Kafka 0.9.0.0.